# Problems with threads and hibernate sessions

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate, repository

Im using hibernate 3 and spring.
When I start a thread an exception occurred:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
```

I dont know how to detach entities or close session with this architecture.
I appreciate some help.

`CommunicationService.sendCommunications()` code:

```
public void sendCommunications(HibernateMessageToSendRepository messageToSendRepository)  {
    Long messageId = new Long(41); //this is only for test. the idea is get a list of id and generate a thread group.
    MessageSender sender = SmsSender(messageId, messageToSendRepository);
    sender.start();
}
```

Invoking `sendCommunications` code:

```
ApplicationContext appCont = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("appContext.xml");      
ServiceLocator serviceLocator = ServiceLocator.getInstance();
HibernateMessageToSendRepository messageToSendRepository = (HibernateMessageToSendRepository) appCont.getBean("messageToSendRepository");

CommunicationService communication = serviceLocator.getCommunicationService();
communication.sendCommunications(messageToSendRepository);
```

SmsSender (extends from MessageSender (thread)) code:

```
public class SmsSender extends MessageSender {

    public SmsSender(Long messageToSendId, HibernateMessageToSendRepository messageToSendRepository) {
        super(messageToSendRepository);
        MessageToSend messageToSendNew = this.messageToSendRepository.getById(messageToSendId);     
        this.messageToSend = messageToSendNew;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            MessageToSendSms messageToSendSms = (MessageToSendSms) this.messageToSend;
            Iterator<CustomerByMessage> itCbmsgs = messageToSendSms.getCustomerByMessage().iterator();          
            while (itCbmsgs.hasNext()) {                
                CustomerByMessage cbm = (CustomerByMessage) itCbmsgs.next();                        

                //sms sending
                this.getGateway().sendSMS(cbm.getBody(), cbm.getCellphone());                       
                cbm.setStatus(CustomerByMessageStatus.SENT_OK);
                cbm.setSendingDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());               
            }           

            messageToSendSms.getMessage().setStatus(messageToSendStatus.ALL_MESSAGES_SENT);
            this.messageToSendRepository.update(messageToSendSms);      
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            this.log.error("Error en sms sender " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

`MessageToSendRepository` code:

```
public void update(MessageToSend messageToSend) {
    try {
        this.getSession().update(messageToSend);
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        this.log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to detach `messageToSendNew` after you you retrieve it, but before you share it with another thread. You can detach the object by calling `Session.close()` on your hibernate session.

Caveat you must eagerly populate all the fields that you need.

If you need to reconnect it with a new session you can use the `merge()` method.

Comment: my bad `detach()` is part of the API the appropriate way to detach the object is to close your session.